# Transferring my PSN email address

Tags: ps3, psn

I wanted to make a new PSN account, because my name was kinda too revealing, as it included both my first name and last name, so I first changed the e-mail on my old account, then I went to go sign up for the new account. I put in my e-mail address that was previously being used by the old account and it said that I need to go to the PSN website and sign in, so I went to the website and typed in the e-mail address I had typed in while signing up and it said that the e-mail address was incorrect, help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to be able to make a new account you will need to go and create a brand new Email Address  and then sign up using the new email. You can only use your old one if your recovering your account. Second Option: You could pay to change your name on PSN.

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, how much do I need to pay?

Comment: I'm on ps3 by the way

Comment: alright I think I'm probably gonna just make a new email adress thanks mate

Comment: No Problem Mate. Hope I've Helped You!